# Running c-program through PHP (raspberry Pi)

Tags: php, c, raspberry-pi, exec

In my third if statement I want to run a C-program on the raspberry Pi when I press the button. I'm lost as how to do this.

Right now the C-program is just going to light up an LED and it works if I just run the compiled program, but I can't figure out how to do it through the PHP.

I've read somewhere to use "exec", but I don't know how to do that (I'm relatively new to programming).

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<form method=GET action="index.php">

<input name="button" type="submit" value="Turnon">
<input name="button" type="submit" value="Turnoff">
<input name="button" type="submit" value="ON">
<input name="button" type="submit" value="OFF">

</form>


<?php



if ($_GET["button"] == "Turnon")
   {
    system ( "gpio mode 28 out" );
    system ( "gpio write 28 1" );
   };

if ($_GET["button"] == "Turnoff")
   {
    system ( "gpio mode 28 out" );
    system ( "gpio write 28 0" );
   };

if ($_GET["button"] == "ON")
   {
    system("sudo /home/pi/var/www/blink.exe >/dev/null 2>/dev/null & ");
   };

if ($_GET["button"] == "OFF")
   {
    system ( "gpio mode 28 out" );
    system ( "gpio write 28 0" );
   };

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [shellexec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) command in PHP?

Comment: As I said, I'm pretty new to programming, so I really don't know how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

in your code:

```
<?php
exec("gpio mode 28 out", $output);
print_r($output);
```

$output contains the result of your script

Comment: In the end I don't need a LED to light up though? I just need to be able to run a c program on the raspberry (through the php which is also on the raspberry).
The LED program is just to test, whether it works or not.
I actually need to write to a display, and this is why I need the c program.
If you can do this with what you send me, I'm sorry, but I don't understand

Comment: you said you dont know how to use exec, exec works like a terminal(command prompt) where you can execute any script or command. the exec function will store the output of that command in the $output variable.

Comment: to run a c program, which is an .exe format. `exec("path_to_exe_file/file.exe", $output)`

Comment: It's still not working. The LED will not light up when I press the button.

Comment: if ($_GET["button"] == "THIS")

     {

        exec("/home/pi/var/www/blink.exe", $output);

     };

Comment: does running /home/pi/var/www/blink.exe from terminal work?

Comment: you have to build the program separately for raspbery pi, you can not run windows build files, the program built for linux will not have a .exe extension.

Comment: Yes I can run it just fine from the terminal.
Everything is on the raspberry? Both the c-file, php-file and the exe-file (I have two exe files, one called "blink" and one called "blink.exe" because I thought that may have been the problem, but neither works)

Comment: Never mind... I had to change the /etc/sudoer file and now it works (I'm using system and not exec though)